# How to skip over a certain index position for txt file

Tags: python

I have an assignment that requires me to analyze data for presidential job creation without using dictionaries. I have to open a text file and average data that applies to the democratic and republican presidents. I am having trouble understanding how to skip over certain lines (in my case I don't want to include the first line and index position 0, the years and months). This is what I have so far and a bit of the input file:

```
Year,Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec
1979,14090,14135,14152,14191,14221,14239,14288,14328,14422,14484,14532,14559
1980,14624,14747,14754,14795,14827,14784,14861,14870,14824,14900,14903,14946
1981,14969,14981,14987,14985,14971,14963,14993,15007,14971,15028,15073,15075
1982,15056,15056,15050,15075,15132,15207,15299,15328,15403,15463,15515,15538

def g_avg():
infile = open("government_employment_Windows.txt", 'r')

lines = []
for line in infile:
    print(line)
    lines.append(line)
infile.close()
print(lines)

mean = 0
for line in lines:
    number = float(line)
    mean = mean + number
mean = mean / len(lines)
print(mean)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there sample (small) example of input file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a very very pythonic way to calculate this

```
with open('filename') as f:
        lines = f.readlines() #Read the lines of the txt
sum = 0
n = 0
for line in lines[1:]:     #Use the [1:] to skip the first row with the months
    row = line.split(',')  #Use the split to convert the line in a list separated by comma
    for element in row[1:]:  #Use the [1:] to skip the years
        sum += float(element)
        n += 1
mean = sum/ n
```

Answer (score 1):

This also looks like a csv file, in which case you can use the built in csv module

```
import csv

total = 0
count = 0
with open("government_employment_Windows.txt", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) #skips the headers
    for line in reader:
        for item in line[1:]:
            count += 1
            total += float(item)

print(total)
print(count)
print('average: ', total/count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a slice to skip over the first line, i.e `file.readlines[1:]`

```py
# foo.txt
line, that, you, want, to, skip
important, stuff
other, important, stuff
```

```py
with open('foo.txt') as file:
    for line in file.readlines()[1:]:
        print(line)
```

> important, stuff
>
> other, important, stuff

Note that since I have used `with` to open a file, Python will close it for me automatically. If you have just done `file = open(..)` you will have to also do `file.close()`